# Why is the current limited to 0.8A while switching this inductive load?

Tags: mosfet-driver, switching, inductive

How can I increase the current in this setup? I tried increasing the gate on pulse and the inductance (L) but couldn't achieve a higher current. Any other suggestion on this?

[image]

Comment: Is U2 a MOSFET? What if you change it to another one?

Comment: Yes its MOSFET, tried changing to other NMOS current is raising up

Comment: Not wise to switch capacitive load directly (33n), btw. It causes an infinitive current flow theoretically.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I'm curious what theory has unlimited bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always start by reading the datasheet:

[UJ3C120150K3S](https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/UJ3C120150K3S)

Rds(on) is measured at Vgs = 12V.  You are applying 5V.  Vgs(th) is 4.4V typical, so it'll be barely over the test condition Id = 10mA at 5V.  700mA is "barely over" in the grand scheme of things, so this seems an adequate explanation of the observation.

Proposed solution: increase Vgs(on) to 12V.

If you're limited in an application by having a logic supply and no intermediate voltage, you'll have to determine some way to derive it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a limitation from your MOSFET (model). To tell for sure, look into the .model statement for it or build a test bench.

Assuming the model is correct, your MOSFET is not suited for the task. Choose a larger one with higher current capacity.